# How to specify HTML attributes for options of a select tag that is created using laravel form builder?

Tags: php, laravel, formbuilder

You can set HTML attributes for the `<select>` itself but what about the `<options>`?

`Form::select('name', $options, null, ['class'=>'form-control'])`

Answer (score 4):

First parameter is the `id` and `name` attribute, second param is the array with values of `<select>`, third parameter is selected option and fourth parameter is array with HTML attributes. If you want to set `name`, `class` or another HTML attribute simply put it into the array (can't set `id` with the array, must use first param):

```
// View
{{ Form::select('selectname', $selectname, Input::old('selectname'), array('class'=>'form-control', 'name'=>'modified_name')) }}
```

EDIT1: I misunderstood the question, the only way to set HTML attributes to `<option>` is using `Form::macro` and build `<option>` tags dynamically.

---

EDIT2: You should build something like this:

```
Form::macro('test', function($name, $list = array(), $options = array())
{
$build = array();

foreach ($list as $key => $value)
{
    $build[] = sprintf('<option id="%s" name="%s" class="%s" value="%s">%s</option>', $name, $name, $options['class'], $value->id, $value->name);
}
return join("\n", $build);
});
```

And then use it into your view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'test')) }}
    {{ Form::test('test', $list, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Result:

```
<option id="test" name="test" class="form-control" value="1">Test1</option>
<option id="test" name="test" class="form-control" value="2">Test2</option>
<option id="test" name="test" class="form-control" value="3">Test3</option>
```

You can add `<select>` tags into macro and pass some arguments to the function for HTML attributes of it or simply add `<select>` tags to the view with proper attributes.